# Strange AutoScroll behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Introduction**

I have written a simple user control.

The control contains a FlowLayoutPanel and a button on it.

The button click event handler is as follows:

```
private void uxAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "Label " + count.ToString();
    uxFlowLayout.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

The `Add` button adds a label onto the `FlowLayoutPanel` and because the `FlowLayoutPanel.AutoSize` and control's `AutoSize` properties are equal to true and `FlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection` is equal to `TopDown` the control will be increased in height.

I've put my user control on a form and set the form's `AutoScroll` property to true.

Also I wrote the following *Layout* event handler:

```
private void MainForm_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    uxSection.Width = this.ClientSize.Width;
}
```

(*uxSection* is a user control that I'm talking about in the beginning of the **Introduction** section)

**Problem**

Here is what I'm doing:

**Step 0**. Run the program.

[image]

**Step 1**. Add a few labels so that the vertical scrollbar will appear.

[image]

**Step 2**. Scroll to the bottom of the form.

[image]

**Step 3**. Resize the form horizontally.

[image]

As you can see, after resizing the form, the scrollbar position is not at the bottom (I expect it to be at the bottom).

So the question is, what am I missing? Why does the scrollbar resets to the top?

Comment: Why does it look like the scroll bar is on the form and not on the UserControl?  Is the button inside the FlowLayoutPanel, too?  Labels can't get focus, but your button can, which is why it is scrolling back into view.  WinForms is trying to help the user show the active control on the screen.

Comment: @LarsTech: thank you for the tip. After some google searching I've found a workaround here: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/c-panel-resets-scroll-position-after-focus-is-lost-and-regained/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the whole control is redrawn upon a resize.

You'll want to either keep the location of the scrollbar saved in a variable so that when the resize event occurs you can reset the position of the scrollbar OR you'll want to push the scroll bar to the bottom of the list when a resize event is fired by using the number of items in your list to calculate where the bottom element is and then pushing the scrollbar to that position.